# Is there a word for wanting, or craving, power

Tags: single-word-requests

The title is self-explanatory. Is there a word for the desire to have power, or should I just use the phrase?

Comment: The only word that I can think of is "Ambitious", but it may not mean it as strongly as craving power. There might also be "Power-Loving", but not sure if you can count it as one word.

Comment: Presumably this is **not** *megalomania,* "Obsession with the exercise of power" -- your person with this desire doesn't actually have power yet? A sample sentence, as required by the tag, would help greatly.

Answer (score 7):

You can describe someone as being **[power-hungry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/power-hungry)**:

> adjective: Having a strong desire for power.
>
> *‘the power-hungry and evil dictator’*

<sup>Oxford dictionaries</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> **megalomaniac**

[*Obsession with the exercise of power.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/megalomania)

[If you describe someone as a megalomaniac, you are criticizing them because they enjoy being powerful, or because they believe that they are more powerful or important than they really are.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/megalomaniac)

Answer (score 1):

You may use *powermad*. Here's an example from [*The Empowered Leader*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22powermad%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en#q=%22powermad%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=10&*) by C Miller:

> I suspect that most **powermad** leaders never define themselves that way. Their erosion to the abusive use of power was so gradual that they may not have seen it.

and one from a [biography of Theodore Roosevelt](https://books.google.com/books?id=tJr46cUdnh4C&pg=PT37&dq=%22powermad%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP6OPe2svSAhUHYiYKHS5IC5U4HhDoAQg-MAY#v=onepage&q=%22powermad%22&f=false) by L L Gould:

> To a significant portion of his party, moreover, [Theodore] Roosevelt seemed a **powermad** radical lusting for a return to the highest office in the land.

Comment: I fear that this word shows the effects that power has once grasped and will not help me convey my idea.

Comment: @KidusAmare You are, of course, the sole judge of your vocabulary, but I think your fear is groundless. *Powermad* is usually used to describe those grasping for power. I've added a quote. TR was President from 1901 to 1909, and there was an informal taboo (broken by his cousin in 1940) against a third term, a taboo which TR recognized by pledging not to seek a third term. He kept that promise in 1908, but broke it in 1912. So he wasn't seen as driven mad by power in 1908, but he was seen as such by seeking power in 1912.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a noun, change Marcello's suggestion into ' megalomania'

Comment: You could suggest this as an edit to Marcello's (earlier) answer...

Answer (score 0):

***[Thirst for power](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thirst%20for%20power&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthirst%20for%20power%3B%2Cc0)*** is an idiomatic expression that is often used to convey the idea.

Usages:

[Thirst for power](https://www.marxists.org/archive/trotsky/1937/xx/thirst.pdf) is also a book by Leon Trotsky

[Hitler's Thirst For Power](https://www.kibin.com/essay-examples/tag/hitler%2527s-thirst-for-power)  Essay Examples

From [Invisible Power](https://books.google.it/books?id=Lor4zbh3JOwC&q=%22thirst%20for%20power%22&dq=%22thirst%20for%20power%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDzcy91svSAhUEPRQKHQOoBmUQ6AEINjAE):

> - Pigott was described as "***an iron-fisted decision-maker who cannot satisfy a thirst for power***."The NCC chief reacted like a bemused parent, retorting that Ottawa is not a playground merely for the residents, ......

Comment: Does that mean there is no one word for it?

Comment: @KidusAmare - I can't think of any with the same impact. Is it a problem of space?

Comment: Not space but rather impact. I want a word that will have an enforcing feeling on first sight. Single words usually have more of this effect than phrases, especially ones used commonly.

Comment: I agree, let's see if other users have other suggestions. As for impact, the expression suggested above is very strong.

Comment: power-hungry . . .

Answer (score 0):

[David McLelland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_McClelland), an American psychologist, studied human needs and motivations.  One human need he identified was the need for power, which he abbreviated  [nPow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_power).

McClelland defines nPow as a desire for power either to control other people (for [one's] own goals) or to achieve higher goals (for the greater good), and describes people high in this trait as seeking neither recognition nor approval from others, but only agreement and compliance. Prsons with a high nPow score are likely to seek power over others.

So someone who desires power can be said to have a high nPow score.